# Creating Dynamic SQL using += will in some cases truncate the previous content

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation

In some situations, I got a weird behavior on SQL Server 2012 (latest update) when trying to generate a string using self concatenation

```
@Str += ...
```

or

```
@Str = @Str + ...
```

It's truncating the previous content of the variable within the query, which is the expected behavior when concatenating a NULL value except I'm not...

Here is a simplified version of the code reduced to the minimum to reproduce the bug on my instance. It's hard to reproduce as just copying the function result to a temp table (which is impossible in my case) fixes it, so I'm suspecting something around query planning or optimization.

```
DECLARE @CTESQL VARCHAR(MAX)= '';

SELECT 
    --TOP 4096--Workaround for SQL SERVER bug dropping previous text in some cases (4096 = max statement in a select clause)
    @CTESQL+= CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PvtColumnName) THEN '1'
              ELSE CASE WHEN LAG(PvtColumnName) OVER (ORDER BY PvtColumnName) <> ISNULL(PvtColumnName,
                                                              ColumnName)
                        THEN '2'
                   ELSE '3'
                   END
              END + CASE WHEN PvtColumnName IS NULL THEN '4'
                    ELSE (CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.PvtColumnName DESC)
                               THEN '5'
                          ELSE '6'
                          END)
                    END
FROM
    dbo.ImportDefinition('stgPopulation') t
ORDER BY
    PvtColumnName
  , ColumnId

PRINT (@CTESQL);
```

The table function 'ImportDefinition' is returning the following data:

```
PvtColumnName       ColumnId    ColumnName
------------------- ----------- --------------------
NULL                3           Country
NULL                2           GMPSubRegion
NULL                4           ISO_Ctry
NULL                9           Source
AgeGroupCode        6           Total
AreaTypeCode        6           Total
AgeGroupCode        7           Under5
AreaTypeCode        7           Under5
AgeGroupCode        8           Urban
AreaTypeCode        8           Urban
NULL                1           RegionFullName
NULL                5           Year
```

the expected result is :

```
343414343434363636363625
```

the actual result from SQL Server  is :

```
25
```

A simple work around is to use 'TOP n' which fix it but I don't know why and it's pretty dirty.

I had some hope that forcing MAXDOP 1 would help but no luck there.

It is the 2nd time I'm running against this issue so despite having multiple workaround I'd really would like to understand what is happening or if there is a bug somewhere.

Thank you for your expertise.

**EDIT**
Here is a script that allow to reproduce the same behavior:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
    (
     F1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
   , F2 NVARCHAR(4000) NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY];

GO
INSERT  INTO dbo.MyTable
        (F1, F2)
VALUES
        ('foo', 'a')
,       ('faa', 'b')
,       ('fuu', 'a');


DECLARE @CTESQL VARCHAR(MAX)= '';

SELECT
    @CTESQL+= CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY F2)
                   THEN '1'
                   ELSE CASE WHEN LAG(F2) OVER (ORDER BY F2) <> ISNULL(F2,
                                                              F1)
                             THEN '2'
                             ELSE '3'
                        END
              END + CASE WHEN F2 IS NULL THEN '4'
                         ELSE (CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY F2 DESC)
                                    THEN '5'
                                    ELSE '6'
                               END)
                    END
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    F2;

PRINT (@CTESQL);
```

Comment: If you change the underlying data so that the last "25" will not get generated, do you get "36" or do you get an empty string or NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry just re-read and noticed that copying the results of the function to a table prevents the issue from reproducing.

Unless you want to create scripts for the base table(s) and table-valued function that would allow others to reproduce the issue, the best anyone can do is guess.

My first guess is that your function isn't returning the results you think, but if it is, then there is something about the interplay between a TVF and the **undocumented** technique you are using to build a string from query results.

I highlight **undocumented** to remind you that is exactly what this technique that you are using is, and it is impossible to say that there is a "bug" in undocumented behavior.   SQL was never intended to work the way you are using it, and it's just chance that it happens to work that way most of the time, but there is no guarantee that it will work that way all the time, or at all in future versions.   Even fixing it with `TOP n` is undocumented and may not work in a future version of SQL Server.

The better solution would be to start using `STUFF()` to do your string concatenation.   There are already numerous examples of how to do this on this site and elsewhere on the internet.

As to the question "Why isn't this working?", I suspect the best answer you're going to get is: "It's undocumented behavior.   Who knows?"

EDIT in response to comments:

1. The undocumented technique I am referring to is the building of a string variable using +=.   See [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/), and scroll down to the section called "Unreliable Approaches".   The approach you are using is the second one listed, "Scalar UDF with variable concatenation in SELECT", although you are not using it in a UDF.   Still, the technique of `SELECT @var = @var + SomeData...` is the part that undocumented and therefore unreliable.
2. The "solution using STUFF()" I was referring to is the same as the one proposed by SqlZim in his answer.  The same solution employs both `STUFF()` and `FOR XML`.  As shorthand, I referred to it as using `STUFF()`, as I knew a search on that keyword would lead to that solution.

Comment: Dear Tab Alleman,
Which technique do you refere as undocumented?

I've been able to get the issue reproduced using table instead of TVF.
I do agree to `Top n` isn't a solution.

Comment: I've tested STUFF() with no conclusive result and CONCAT() return the same result.

Comment: See edits to my answer above.   If you can reproduce the issue with a Table (no TVF), then can you edit your question and add a script to create a table that will reproduce the issue with the query you posted?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to reproduce your issue was by removing the '+' in @ctesql+=.

You might give the stuff() version below a try and see if you have the same issue.

```sql
use TempDb
go
set nocount on;
--if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '#ImportDefinition%') begin; drop table #ImportDefinition; end;
--/*
if not exists (select * from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '#ImportDefinition%')
begin;
create table #ImportDefinition (PvtColumnName nvarchar(16) ,ColumnId smallint ,ColumnName nvarchar(16) ) 
insert into #ImportDefinition values  (null ,'3' ,'Country') ,(null ,'2' ,'GMPSubRegion') ,(null ,'4' ,'ISO_Ctry') ,(null ,'9' ,'Source') ,('AgeGroupCode' ,'6' ,'Total') ,('AreaTypeCode' ,'6' ,'Total') ,('AgeGroupCode' ,'7' ,'Under5') ,('AreaTypeCode' ,'7' ,'Under5') ,('AgeGroupCode' ,'8' ,'Urban') ,('AreaTypeCode' ,'8' ,'Urban') ,(null ,'1' ,'RegionFullName') ,(null ,'5' ,'Year');
end;
-- select * from #ImportDefinition
--*/
declare @ctesql varchar(max)= '';
--/*
select 
 @ctesql+=(case when 1 = row_number() over (order by pvtcolumnname) then '1'
                when lag(pvtcolumnname) over (order by pvtcolumnname) <> isnull(pvtcolumnname, columnname) then '2'
                    else '3'
              end) 
        + (case when pvtcolumnname is null then '4'
                when 1 = row_number() over (order by t.pvtcolumnname desc) then '5'
                  else '6'
              end)
  from #importdefinition t
  order by pvtcolumnname, columnid;
print (@ctesql);

declare @ForXmlPath varchar(max)
select @ForXmlPath = stuff((select 
          (case when 1 = row_number() over (order by pvtcolumnname) then '1'
                when lag(pvtcolumnname) over (order by pvtcolumnname) <> isnull(pvtcolumnname, columnname) then '2'
                    else '3'
              end) 
        + (case when pvtcolumnname is null then '4'
                when 1 = row_number() over (order by t.pvtcolumnname desc) then '5'
                  else '6'
              end)
    from #importdefinition t
    order by pvtcolumnname, columnid
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,0,'');
print @ForXmlPath;
--*/
print char(10);
print @@version;
declare @options int = @@options;
print 'disable_def_cnst_chk'   + case when 1 & @options = 1         then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'implicit_transactions'  + case when 2 & @options = 2         then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'cursor_close_on_commit' + case when 4 & @options = 4         then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'ansi_warnings'          + case when 8 & @options = 8         then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'ansi_padding'           + case when 16 & @options = 16       then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'ansi_nulls'             + case when 32 & @options = 32       then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'arithabort'             + case when 64 & @options = 64       then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'arithignore'            + case when 128 & @options = 128     then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'quoted_identifier'      + case when 256 & @options = 256     then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'nocount'                + case when 512 & @options = 512     then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'ansi_null_dflt_on'      + case when 1024 & @options = 1024   then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'ansi_null_dflt_off'     + case when 2048 & @options = 2048   then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'concat_null_yields_null'+ case when 4096 & @options = 4096   then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'numeric_roundabort'     + case when 8192 & @options = 8192   then ' on' else ' off' end;
print 'xact_abort'             + case when 16384 & @options = 16384 then ' on' else ' off' end;
go
```

results in this:

```sql
343414343434363636363625
343414343434363636363625


Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
    May 14 2014 18:34:29 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

disable_def_cnst_chk off
implicit_transactions off
cursor_close_on_commit off
ansi_warnings on
ansi_padding on
ansi_nulls on
arithabort on
arithignore off
quoted_identifier on
nocount on
ansi_null_dflt_on on
ansi_null_dflt_off off
concat_null_yields_null on
numeric_roundabort off
xact_abort off
```

Comment: thank you SqlZim,
Using FOR XML seams to work on the simplied version.
I'll try to implement the full function tomorrow and get back to you.

Even so I'm still curious ;)

Comment: FYI 
my @@version is:
`Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU2) (KB3137746) - 11.0.6523.0 (X64) 
 Mar  2 2016 21:29:16 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`